# Tridion and SmartTarget: tcdl tags converted to <smarttarget:xxx> instead of <tridion:xxx>

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, smarttarget

I installed SmartTarget 2011 SP1 on a Tridion 2011 environment (.NET) following the instructions in SDL Live Content.

The problem is that When I publish a page, all my

```xml
<tcdl:xxxx>
```

tags are converted into

```xml
<smarttarget:xxx>
```

The bad thing is that

```xml
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation>
```

is also transformed into

```xml
<smarttarget:ComponentPresentation>
```

instead of

```xml
<tridion:ComponentPresentation>
```

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Edited to add TCDLEngine section of cd_deployer_conf.xml (I deleted commented lines):

```xml
<TCDLEngine> 
    <Properties> 
        <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="controls"/>  
        <Property Name="tcdl.jsp.style" Value="tags"/>  
    <Property Name="aspnet.tagprefix" Value="tridion" />
    <Property Name="aspnet.tagprefix" Value="smarttarget" />
    </Properties>  

    <TagBundle Resource="com/tridion/smarttarget/tcdl/tagbundle.xml"/>
</TCDLEngine>
```

Comment: Can you post what you have in the TCDLEngine section of the cd_deployer_conf file for the target that's processing the deployment packages?

Comment: Yeah, this sure looks like an issue with the TCDL mappings, I've seen this before. Please post the TCDLEngine section as Jeremy asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following elements for your Deployer config:

```xml
<Property Name="aspnet.tagprefix" Value="tridion" />
<Property Name="aspnet.tagprefix" Value="smarttarget" />
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I wonder why SmartTarget installer adds those two lines.

Comment: That would seem like a defect in the installer... I'll raise it with the team.

Comment: The installer adds to a CD config file? I never knew that - clearly you do learn something new every day :)

Comment: You can let the installer configure Content Deployer: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP1/task_B06B7DD01FBC46E0A7EB9C06902564F5